# Regexp: Allow only use of a few words and only once per word

Tags: javascript, html, regex

```js
var string;
string = 'test';
console.log((/(test)+/g).test(string));//i want true
string = 'another test';
console.log((/(test)+/g).test(string));//i want false
string = 'test test';
console.log((/((\w)+(\w){3,}).*?\1/g).test(string));//this work, but i want chose the words
string = 'test test';
console.log((/((test)+(\w)+).*?\1/g).test(string));//this don't work, i can't chose 'test'
```

If there is an unpredictable word I want to always return false.
I have a string of words, and if I find an unpredictable word in the string I want a false one, so I always see true, because only control if the word is found.
Sorry for english, translated by google.

Comment: Can you add more example?

Comment: Do you mean that no other word than the specific word (in your examples **test**) can be present in the string?

Comment: @ClasG I want only the word object of the string to be present and not repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could make of the question, you need to return `true` only if the complete string is composed of the word you want.

This regex `/^( ?test ?)+$/` should work for you.

This will force the string to start and end with the word test and will allow a space between the words.

Comment: ( ?test ?)+.*?\1 on string 'test another' return false, i want true, because i need to stop i see a word different from test

Answer (score 1):

So, you whant to match if in a string there are multiple occurrence of a given string, right? you can use the RegExp object to make a dynamic regexp pattern:

```js
var search = 'test';
var reg = new RegExp('('+search+').*?\\1','g');

console.log(reg.test('test')); // false
console.log(reg.test('test test')); // true
console.log(reg.test('another test')); // false
console.log(reg.test('test another test')); //true
```

Comment: console.log(reg.test('another test')); is false, how can it become true? I would like a positive though if you use unforeseen words as here is the word 'another'

Comment: Uhm... Can you  provide some more example? In not sure about What you need